# How to fix breadcrumbs and page title showing html tags on frontend

Tags: custom-titlebar

Can somebody help me to fix breadcrumbs and page title showing HTML tags on frontend? I'm using Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

I have set "`attribute name set to Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: Yes`".

My breadcrumbs is as follows:

```html
Home / New Products / <span>Angels & Cowboys</span> Sonoma County Proprietary Red 2012.
```

On the Page Title it also shows:

```html
<span>Angels & Cowboys</span> Sonoma County Proprietary Red 2012.
```

On shopping cart page it also shows:

```html
    <span>Angels & Cowboys</span> Sonoma County Proprietary Red 2012.
```

This has been ongoing issue for few versions of Magento lately.

Many thanks.

Comment: you image is missing??

Comment: They don't allow me to post image. But my breadcrumbs show like this: Home / New Products / <span>Angels & Cowboys</span> Sonoma County Proprietary Red 2012. On the Page Tittle it also show <span>Angels & Cowboys</span> Sonoma County Proprietary Red 2012. This has been ongoing issue for few versions of Magento lately.